# Dockerfile not properly running

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a web application written in Flask and it is working fine in localhost setup. Now i want to make it dockerized in a container and want to run it via docker. The issue is when I start the docker image it is running the same way as it is in the localhost setup. This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

#Setting up virtual environment

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/ranji/FlaskApp/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# Install dependencies:
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN /home/ranji/FlaskApp/venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt


COPY app.py .
COPY regor_GP_20_v1.pkl .
COPY index.html .
COPY logger.sqlite3 .

# Run the application:
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

My idea is to have this in a docker container and I want to run it from there. I strongly believe that I'm missing some commands or wrongly doing something. Any help would be obliged.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEXJT.png)
[Bash logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2i0e.png)

Comment: What is the command you use for running the docker container?

Comment: ```docker run docker-app:3.0```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the port mapping to your docker run command.

`docker run -p 7000:7000 docker-app:3.0`

Otherwise the port used inside the docker container is not available outside of the container. By exposing it this way, you should be able to access it through 127.0.0.1:7000

Comment: Sorry. It's again showing the same output as to previous.

Comment: You might want to also change your application to use 127.0.0.1 instead of the 0.0.0.0 if it's still not working.

Comment: I tried using ```0.0.0.0:7000``` to connect it is working now. Thanks for the suggestion! But the only problem now persists is that it is showing ```curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer```. Any counter measures to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose a port in order to access the application.

```
EXPOSE 7000 
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Make sure your python app is exposing 7000 port as well

Comment: "The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port." - Docker Documentation. It needs to be specifically exposed by with -p 7000:7000